# AWS Lambda function timing out after successful completion

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that does work successfully. I am able to create a file on S3 and another FTP server. The issue is even after successfull completion it time outs. It just doesn't finish executing. I could see from the logs it takes around 2 seconds and the timeout specified is 5 seconds. How do I make my function stops as soon as it is done? Here is the complete code:

```
"use strict";

var config = require('./config/dev');
var sql = require("mssql");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var PromiseFtp = require('promise-ftp');
var fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    GetDataFromServer(event, context, callback);
};

function GetDataFromServer(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("Fetching data from database...");
    var keys = [], outputText = '';
    sql.connect(config.db, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
            return callback(true, 'Error in fetching records from database...');
        }
        else {
            new sql.Request()
                .input('ClientId', sql.Int, 469)
                .execute('ForesightDailyDataPull', (err, result) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        //Create Text here and assign to "outputText"
                        CreateFileOnS3(outputText, event, context, callback);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Error in fetching records from database...');
                        return callback(true, 'Error in fetching records from database...');
                    }
                })
        }
    });
    sql.on('error', err => {
        console.log('Error in fetching records from database...');
        return callback(true, 'Error in fetching records from database...');
    })
}

function CreateFileOnS3(fileData, event, context, callback) {
    const fileName = generateFileName();
    console.log('Sending file to S3...');
    const s3 = new AWS.S3(config.awsCredentials);
    const params = {
        Bucket: config.app.s3Bucket,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: fileData
    };
    s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
        if (s3Err) {
            console.log('There was an error creating file on S3');
            return callback(true, 'There was an error creating file on S3');
        }
        else {
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
            CreatefileOnFTP(fileData, fileName, event, context, callback);
        }
    });
}

function CreatefileOnFTP(fileData, fileName, event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Sending file to FTP...');
    var ftpObject = {
        "fileData": fileData,
        "fileName": fileName,
        "ftpURL": config.ftpDetails.ftpProtocol + "://" + config.ftpDetails.host,
        "ftpUserName": config.ftpDetails.user,
        "ftpPassword": config.ftpDetails.password
    };
    request({
        url: config.ftpUploadURL,
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        body: ftpObject
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('File sent successfully to FTP server.');
            return callback(null, 'File sent successfully to FTP...');
        }
        else {
            console.log('An error occurred while sending file to FTP.');
            return callback(true, 'Error in sending file to FTP...');
        }
    });
}

function generateFileName() {
    var _d = new Date(),
        y = _d.getFullYear(),
        m = _d.getMonth() + 1,
        d = _d.getDate();
    return y + '-' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d < 10 ? '0' + d : d) + '.txt';
}
```

Comment: AWS Lambda continues the Lambda function invocation until the event loop is empty. Your good path does appear to invoke the provided callback with null as the first parameter, so perhaps your event loop is not empty?

Comment: @jarmod I am not sure how to make event loop empty. Is there any way to stop executing the function.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that's the cause, but it's an important statement about how the Lambda service knows that a Lambda function is complete (it's not just that the function returned or that the callback was made). If you increase the timeout from 5s to 30s, does it complete processing at 2s and then timeout at 30s? I wonder if your MySQL and/or FTP client objects are the cause? Could you try closing/tearing those down explicitly to test? I'm assuming that you're definitely seeing the log "File sent successfully to FTP..." some time before the Lambda times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the open sql connection after the function completes by calling `sql.close()` after the action resolves.

```
function GetDataFromServer(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("Fetching data from database...");
    var keys = [], outputText = '';
    sql.connect(config.db, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
            return callback(true, 'Error in fetching records from database...');
        }
        else {
            new sql.Request()
                .input('ClientId', sql.Int, 469)
                .execute('ForesightDailyDataPull', (err, result) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        //Create Text here and assign to "outputText"
                        CreateFileOnS3(outputText, event, context, callback);
                        sql.close() //HERE
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Error in fetching records from database...');
                        sql.close() //HERE
                        return callback(true, 'Error in fetching records from database...');

                    }
                })
        }
    });
    sql.on('error', err => {
        console.log('Error in fetching records from database...');
        sql.close() //HERE
        return callback(true, 'Error in fetching records from database...');
    })
}
```